# passing arguments in django

Tags: django, forms, search

I am implementing a search function in django and I want to use ListView. how do a pass the search string to my function in views.py? 
here is my view function that I want to modify:

```
class PersonList(ListView):

    model=Person
    context_object_name='persons'
```

and here is the template:

```
<form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0" name="search" action="{% url 'artdb:search' %}" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
      <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="text" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search" value="{{name}}">
      <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
    </form>r code here
```

Comment: Once you have the arguments, do you know how you are going to do the actual search filtering? Or is that part of your question as well?

Answer (score 0):

```
    class PersonList(ListView):
        model = Person
        template_name = 'your-template-name.html'
        context_object_name='persons'

        def get_queryset(self):
            search_string = self.request.GET.get('search',None)
            if search_string is None:
                persons = Person.objects.filter()                    
            else:
                persons = Person.objects.filter(name__icontains=search_string)enter code here
            return persons
```

**In your template you need to add this.**

```
<form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0" action="{% url 'artdb:search' %}" method="get">{% csrf_token %}
      <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="text" placeholder="Search" name="search" aria-label="Search" value="{{search}}">
      <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
 </form>
```

**In your urls.py**

from django.conf.urls import url

urlpatterns = [

url(r'^search-result$', views.PersonList.as_view(), name='search'),

]

Comment: almost there: AttributeError: module 'artdb.views' has no attribute 'search'
and in views:     path('search/',views.search,name='search'),

Comment: **In your urls.py**  

`from django.conf.urls import url  

urlpatterns = [  
url(r'^search-result$', views.PersonList.as_view(), name='search'),  
]`

Comment: thanks. I have to change to GET because of this: 
Method Not Allowed (POST): /artdb/search